# sql that select distinct records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like (see the picture).
I want to select from this table, some distinct records. For ex. if in column NE_PRIO is "A" then from column TIME_LEFT_OVERRUN take the positive values between +000 06:00:00 and +000 04:00:00 and the negative values between -000 00:00:01 and -000 02:00:00.

If in column NE_PRIO is "B" then from the column TIME_LEFT_OVERRUN take the positive values between +000 24:00:00 and +000 14:00:00 and if there are negative values take them between -000 00:00:01 and -000 10:00:00.
 [image]

and I want to have only the selected rows!
[image]

Comment: just use a `CASE` in your where clause -- what is the hard part?

Comment: Can you please share the table structure?

Comment: what result you need exactly,provide example

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 0):

And easy approach to this would be to create two separate SELECTs , one for each `NE_PRIO`, and then use an UNION to return them as a single query.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_LIKE_PICTURE WHERE  NE_PRIO = "A" AND (ADD YOUR CONDITIONS)

UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE_LIKE_PICTURE WHERE  NE_PRIO = "B" AND (ADD DIFFERENT CONDITIONS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `or`:

```
select *
from table t
where (ne_prio = 'A' and . . . ) or
      (ne_prio = 'B' and . . .)
```

It is not clear what your data types are, so it is hard to express the rest of the conditions that you mention.